# Why don't I see the fire of a smoke simulation I instanced in another scene?

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, instances, fire

I've made a fire sim in one scene. When I instance the collection containing that sim in another scene, I don't see the fire show up. Is there something special I need to do to make that show up? Is this expected to work?

Comment: Not sure, but is the instanced .blend in the same dir? Blender might not find the baked sim in the new file.

Comment: It's all in one .blend file. Like, it renders fine in the scene I created the sim, but just switch to a different scene with the instanced collection, and it no longer shows up. The other geometry in the instanced collection does though.

Comment: Do you have access to all fire options when you select your fire object in another scene?

Comment: No, since it's an instanced collection containing multiple objects / sub-collections, the physics property panel only shows options to enable force fields and rigid body constraints. The fire options are not available on the instance.